# How to pass data between ViewModels in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this use case where I have a parent view and a child view. Both of the views have their own corresponding ViewModels.

**ParentView:**

```
struct ParentView: View {

  @StateObject var parentViewModel = ParentViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            TextField("Add Name", text: $parentViewModel.newListName)
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                Label("Select Products", systemImage: K.ListIcons.productsNr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ParentViewModel:**

```
class ParentViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Published var newListName: String = ""

  func saveList() {
    // some logic to save to CoreData, method would be called via a button
    // how do I reference "someString" from ChildViewModel in this ViewModel?
  }
}
```

**ChildView:**

```
struct ChildView: View {

    @StateObject var childViewModel = ChildViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("Some element")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        childViewModel.alterData()
                    }      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ChildViewModel:**

```
class ChildViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var someString: String = ""

    func alterData() {
       someString = "Toast"
    }
}
```

My question now is, how do I pass the new value of "someString" from ChildViewModel into the ParentViewModel, in order to do some further stuff with it?
I've tried to create a `@StateObject var childViewModel = ChildViewModel()` reference in the ParentViewModel, but that does obviously not work, as this will create a new instance of the ChildViewModel and therefore not know of the changes made to "someString"

---

**Solution:**
As proposed by Josh, I went with the approach to use a single ViewModel instead of two. To achieve this, the ParentView needs a `.environmentObject(T)` modifier.

ParentView:

```
struct ParentView: View {

  @StateObject var parentViewModel = ParentViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            TextField("Add Name", text: $parentViewModel.newListName)
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                Label("Select Products", systemImage: K.ListIcons.productsNr)
            }
        }
    }.environmentObject(parentViewModel)
}
```

The ChildView then references that environment Object via `@EnvironmentObject` without an initializer:

```
struct ChildView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var parentViewModel: ParentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("Some element")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        parentViewModel.alterData()
                    }      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use view models objects in swiftUI then you wouldn't have this problem. If you you want to group related state vars you can use a struct with mutating funcs.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you would use a binding for this situation:

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var name: String

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                Text("Some element")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        name = "Altered!"
                    }      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the parent:

```
struct ParentView: View {

  @StateObject var parentViewModel = ParentViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            TextField("Add Name", text: $parentViewModel.newListName)
            NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(name: $parentViewModel.newListName)) {
                Label("Select Products", systemImage: K.ListIcons.productsNr)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I think you can remove the `NavigationView` view from `ChildView`. Having it `ParentView` is enough.

Comment: Thanks again for helping!